# Stack Exchange and hardware questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site to ask questions about hardware?

I would like to ask some questions but I don't know if [Super User](https://superuser.com/) site is the correct site to do it

Comment: It would help to know what hardware is involved and what type of question you want to ask,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It depends on the *type* of hardware, and in what *context* you are using that hardware. There are several sites you could ask about hardware:

- If you are a computer enthusiast and have **personal computer hardware**, [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) is the right site to ask about that. From their [On Topic help center page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

  > Super User is for **computer enthusiasts and power users**. If you have a question about …
  >
  > - **computer hardware,** [...]

  Emphasis mine.

  Do read the rest of that page to make sure you understand their exceptions; *separate* hardware (electronic devices like smart phones for example) are off-topic unless you having issues with interfacing them with your PC, as are issues surrounding corporate IT or network topics. If your hardware concerns a server or a router, for example, that'd be off topic too.
- If you are dealing with **Apple hardware** you'll find a dedicated community at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), hardware is [on topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

  > Ask Different is for users of **Apple products**. If you have a question about ...
  >
  > - **Apple hardware** [...]
- If you want to ask about **gaming-specific hardware** (consoles, joysticks, VR headsets, etc.), then you can get more dedicated help at [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). They [list such hardware as on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

  > Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question generally covers things such as …
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > - **Game-specific hardware** and utilities
- If you are dealing with **hardware in a [professional capacity](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity)** (the hardware is used in a production setting and / or you have a sysadmin *mindset*) then [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) is the place to ask. Again, quoting their [On Topic page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic):

  > Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a **professional capacity**.
  >
  > If your question is about…
  >
  > - **Server and Workstation** operating systems, **hardware**, and software. [...]
- There are dedicated sites for the [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) platforms that include the hardware in the topic lists.

Whatever site you feel fits best, *do read their on-topic page in detail*. As always, do your research and share that research, and don't ask open-ended discussion questions.

Answer (score 5):

As an aside to what was already mentioned in [Martijn Pieters' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270704/1803692) there's a few things you can do to find out whether your question is on-topic on a specific site.

For one, as already mentioned in the answer, **every** site in the SE network has their own "On Topic help center page". You can find it under: "sitename.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic"
<sub>exceptions: stackoverflow, superuser, serverfault. They have no SE domain</sub>

Additionally, you could ask on the meta of the specific site. Usually such questions are well recieved.

And last but not least, there's Chat.
Stack Exchange has their own, full-fledged chat system. You can find it at: https://chat.stackexchange.com/
<sub>exceptions: stackoverflow and the parent meta have their own chat</sub>

There every site that I know of has at least one dedicated room. Your best bet when asking such things is chiming in there and just asking ;)