# Should the [hardware] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware) tag is incredibly broad and seems to attract [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545/closet-server-versus-colo) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861/will-this-hardware-be-64bit-windows-server-2008-compatible) [off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534/website-hardware-scaling)-[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169497/best-dual-hd-set-up-for-development) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104864/how-to-install-mac-os-in-lenovo-g50-80).

In cases where the question is on topic the [hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware) does not add any value. There is usually a much more specific tag for the type of hardware being used (eg. [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino), [bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth), [usb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usb))

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hardware/info) also acknowledges that the tag is broad:

> Hardware by itself is very broad and there are many tags for specific hardware version which may be more appropriate. Eg, *flash-memory*, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I totally agree with this.

Looking over the Newest 'hardware' Questions page, out of the 15 latest questions, only one question has a score of 1; 9 have a negative score, and 4 have a score of zero.

Most of these questions should be moved to SuperUser or [other SE sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270704/7127751). The few questions that are on-topic would function fine without the `hardware` tag.