# What hardware questions are on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion

I thought any question that directly affects software performance or OS implementation are very much on-topic for SO, caching policy being an example. However, I see questions closed for "off-topic" such as:

- [kernel memory(virtual address entries) in TLB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471240/kernel-memoryvirtual-address-entries-in-tlb)

while others remain open and have a huge number of upvotes, such as:

- [what is TLB shootdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748384/what-is-tlb-shootdown)

Incidentally, the open question is purely about hardware, while the closed question specifically asks about kernel and user space which (in the context of the question) are OS (i.e., software) concepts rather than hardware.

Comment: These kind of questions tend to be on-topic when they are interesting and off-topic when they are boring.  Fairly sensible, a Q+A site filled with boring Qs isn't going to generate a lot of useful As.  But of course it can never be formalized as a "rule" and there will never be a "this is too boring to belong here" close reason.  I haven't seen a lot of this kind of voting lately btw, we could use some.

Comment: @HansPassant Haha that makes sense. But your argument isn't completely subjective; it would seem to imply very strongly that a question with a couple of answers and/or several upvotes shouldn't be a candidate for closure.

Comment: Your sample size might be too small to draw major conclusions.  Looks like this one bit the dust from a close vote review.  The votes dribbled in later, not usual when its been around for 5+ years and gets thousands of google views.  Good Q+A gets about 1 upvote for every 100 googlers, this one is 1:1000.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, yes. I'm persuaded that it's not as simple as I thought :)

Comment: Just as an FYI, the second question is very old. That matters because the rules have changed over the years. I'm not sure you'd be able to ask the latter on SO anymore. There's no point in closing a 7 year-old question over a rule change

Comment: @Machavity Except that people posting new questions may use that an old open and now off-topic question as justification as to why their question should be allowed as well.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf You're assuming a lot with that. We have notes everywhere telling people not to post SEO questions. Doesn't stop them. It's not going to make any difference if it's open or not. Closing old questions is mainly reserved for off-site resources and opinion based, where they're attracting new bad answers

Comment: @Machavity What am I assuming?  You haven't said :-)  I didn't say it was going to stop them posting, I just said that they would try to justify it being allowed due to other similar questions.  Not an assumption, I've seen it happening.

Answer (score 20):

> What hardware questions are on-topic for SO?

The ones that involve programming.

For example:

- Questions asking how to utilise or communicate with hardware components.
- Questions asking what effects certain code will have on the hardware.
- Questions about emulating hardware.

The following are off-topic though:

- Questions about installing hardware/building a computer.
  Those are probably best asked at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).
- Questions about how circuitry works.
  Those are probably best asked at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).
- Hardware recommendations.
  We have [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Specifically, the question you linked to does seem very much on-topic to me, and it is in the process of being reopened.

We also do have a [hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware) tag, but it's everything but a prime example of good questions.
See also: [Should the [hardware] tag be burninated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327827/should-the-hardware-tag-be-burninated)